# Why are compact and noncompact manifolds without boundary called closed manifolds and open manifolds, respectively?

Tags: terminology, manifolds

Why not just call them compact and noncompact manifolds? Isn't the general assumption that manifolds have empty boundary unless stated otherwise?

Comment: That's what the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold) says - when it is assumed that we are talking about manifolds without boundary, we just use compact for "closed manifold." Probably a historical artifact in naming.

Comment: Weirdly, [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_manifolds) says an open manifold has no compact component. So, to any ant in the manifold, it seems "unbounded."

Comment: If that definition is accurate, it means there are manifolds without boundary that are neither closed nor open.

Comment: Historical inertia.